# Debugging nant Duplicate Target

Tags: nant

Nant is complaining about a duplicate target, and as far as I can tell there is no duplicate. Is there some way to get nant to tell me which buildfiles it has open or is trying to open and where these tasks are so I can debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't found a reasonable debugging solution, I did find that this was related to updating nant. An old buildscript that worked began to break on a "duplicate target" error. This was because a taskfile was included by 2 other taskfiles already included in the project. nant found two different paths to the same task, and thought it was two distinct tasks and consequently flipped.