# How can i find/stop if the file is already included in nant while including a build file

Tags: include, nant

I have 4 files say: A.build, B.build, C.build & Common.build.

B.build & C.build includes Common.build.

I am suppose to call file A.build which internally calls B.build & C.Build.
When i try running this file its give me error Common.build file already included.

Is there any way I can stop including a build file if it's already included....

Answer (score 0):

Nant should be ok with the same file being included more than once, although it can have problems if you use use different cases in the name (such as 'hello.include' and 'HELLO.include' for example). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932481/nant-check-if-include-file-was-already-included) for more details.